Is it usual to delete correct answers here?


I have a question about my Reverse Engineering Stack Exchange post: Help finding CPU/SOC on a board
It seems very strange that my correct (if terse) answer was deleted, yet a marginally more complete answer 5 hours later remains.  
Not very encouraging for a new guy if someone else can come along with the same information and take credit.  

Yes, it is normal, and usual. To give you the most concise answer. The community will never be perfect, nor will your answers. In some cases errors will be made in either direction. I am not a mod so whether there is some collusion going on, I have no idea.

Agreed, the (now accepted) answer basically says the same as your deleted answer. Unfortunately this also seems to have driven you away from our community.

Unfortunately many new users try to post comments as answers because they lack reputation for comments and it's a real problem.
Your answer was a single sentence without details which looked like an attempt to comment from a 1-rep just registered user with a generic username and was flagged both by a high-rep user (not an answer) and the system (Low answer quality score).
In retrospect maybe I was a little trigger-happy but everyone makes mistakes.

Thanks for the context for this user's claim.

@IgorSkochinsky: shouldn't we have undeleted the answer then?
